# firebase + next dont save data in realtime database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

Hello i have big problem, the firebase realtime database dont save data
for example

```
const createUserProfile = (email,user,username) => {
    console.log(email);
    console.log(user)
    const db = getDatabase();
    console.log(db)
    const dbRef = ref(db, 'users/' + user.uid);
    set(dbRef, {
      username,
      email,
      createDate: getDate()
    });
  };
```

In realtime conf i have write true and read true
what i can do? its next js
all data is okay,
console.log(db) response is
[image]

and realtime database dont update

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't pass the Firebase app instance to the `getDatabase()` method.

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#initialize_the_javascript_sdk) in the doc that you need to do

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

// TODO: Replace with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
  // The value of `databaseURL` depends on the location of the database
  databaseURL: "https://DATABASE_NAME.firebaseio.com",
  // ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a reference to the database service
const db = getDatabase(app);  // <= See how we pass the app object
```

Comment: its not working i do it     const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const database = getDatabase(app); and save database in context, and load it in another file and not working still

Comment: We can see that you use either `db` (`const db = getDatabase();`) or `database` (`const database = getDatabase(app); `). Is it like that in your code?